# Canadian origin address in FedEx/UPS Module in Magento unable to retrieve rates (Service not available)

Tags: magento, fedex, ups

In Magento if the origin address (Shipping Settings) is Canada, FedEx & UPS modules will not be able to retrieve rates to the USA and Canada. If the origin address is changed to any US address, FedEx and UPS pull rates instantly. The problem is with CANADA as the origin address.

Has anyone encountered this or possibly have a fix?

ShipSync (FedEx Module community) can pull the rates, however it crashes the shopping cart.

Comment: Was there a problem with the Province that was not provided in requests to FedEx? (I am experiencing this with Magento CE 1.7 with Canada, it is working properly with USA, two separate configurations).

Answer (score 4):

This issue had took me a month to solve.

It is very simple, my web site use US dollar as the currency.

And in the Currency Setup (`System -> Configuration -> Currency Setup`), `Allowed Currencies` multi-select box, I just picked US dollar only. That was my BIG mistake!

**SOLUTION IS: select the country which is your origin shipping country.**

Then I had an other problem: The UPS system return $0 or just your handling fee.

**SOLUTION IS: configure your Currency Rates (System -> Manage Currency Rates)**

Hope this help and good luck!
Tim Nguyen.

Comment: yep right on the money.  For every country/region/(even states & cities possible) there are shipping rates/methods/configurations that must meet the Carrier's specification, one being the currency.